# How to download multiple images and have one progressBar using AsynTask (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-asynctask, download

I want my program to download many images (around 500) from the internet and store them in my external storage. Currently when I download a single image, it shows a progressBar and downloads the image properly. However when I am trying to replicate w/ two images, it gives the Toast for "Download complete" for both images being downloaded, however no progressBar for either image is shown and only the first image is properly downloaded.

Here is the code for my onCreate method for activity.

> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>           //Remove Title bar
>           this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
>           //force portrait orientation. (No landscape orientation).
>           setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
>           setContentView(R.layout.activity_quran);
>
> ```
>     //Instantiate ProgressDialog (Used for downloading quran pages).
>     myProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(QuranActivity.this);
>     myProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading Quran");
>     myProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
>     myProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
>     myProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
>
>     //execute when the downloader must be fired.
>     final DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(QuranActivity.this);
>     DownloadTask second = new DownloadTask(getApplicationContext());
>     myHTTPURL = "https://ia601608.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/10/items/05Quran15LineWhitePageWithVioletBorderWww.Momeen.blogspot.com/05%20Quran%2015%20Line%20[White%20page%20with%20Violet%20border]%20-%20www.Momeen.blogspot.com_jp2.zip&file=05%20Quran%2015%20Line%20[White%20page%20with%20Violet%20border]%20-%20www.Momeen.blogspot.com_jp2/05%20Quran%2015%20Line%20[White%20page%20with%20Violet%20border]%20-%20www.Momeen.blogspot.com_0001.jp2&scale=1&rotate=0";
>     myHTTPURL2 = "https://ia601608.us.archive.org/BookReader/BookReaderImages.php?zip=/10/items/05Quran15LineWhitePageWithVioletBorderWww.Momeen.blogspot.com/05%20Quran%2015%20Line%20[White%20page%20with%20Violet%20border]%20-%20www.Momeen.blogspot.com_jp2.zip&file=05%20Quran%2015%20Line%20[White%20page%20with%20Violet%20border]%20-%20www.Momeen.blogspot.com_jp2/05%20Quran%2015%20Line%20[White%20page%20with%20Violet%20border]%20-%20www.Momeen.blogspot.com_0002.jp2&scale=1&rotate=0";
>
>     //First check if the file has already been created. (Only need to download 1ce, or
>     //in the case where the user deleted the files, we reinstall them again).
>     if (isExternalStorageWritable()) {
>         File makeDirectory = getQuranStorageDir(QuranActivity.this, "Quran_Pages");
>
>             for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
>                 Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
>                 myBundle.putInt("i", i);
>                 if (i == 0) {
>                     downloadTask.execute(myHTTPURL);
>
>                     try {
>                         downloadTask.get();
>                     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>                         e.printStackTrace();
>                     } catch (ExecutionException e) {
>                         e.printStackTrace();
>                     }
>
>                     myProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
>                         @Override
>                         public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
>                             downloadTask.cancel(true);
>                         }
>                     });
>
>
>                 } else {
>                     /*if (downloadTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
>                         downloadTask.execute(myHTTPURL2);
>                     } else if (downloadTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
>                         try {
>                             downloadTask.execute(myHTTPURL2).wait(10000);
>                         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>                             e.printStackTrace();
>                         }
>                     } */
>                     second.execute(myHTTPURL2);
>                     try {
>                         second.get();
>                     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>                         e.printStackTrace();
>                     } catch (ExecutionException e) {
>                         e.printStackTrace();
>                     }
>                   //  downloadTask.execute(myHTTPURL2);
>
>                 }
>             }
>     }
> ```

and this is the code for my AsynTask Class.

> @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
>       private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask {
>           private Context context;
>           private PowerManager.WakeLock myWakeLock;
>
> ```
>     public DownloadTask(Context context) {
>         this.context = context;
>     }
>
>
>     @Override
>     protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
>         InputStream input = null;
>         OutputStream output = null;
>         HttpURLConnection connection = null;
>         try {
>             URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
>             connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
>             connection.setDoOutput(true);
>             connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
>             connection.connect();
>
>             if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
>                 return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
>                         + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
>             }
>
>             //Display download percentage.
>             int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
>
>             //create folder to place the downloaded file in.
>             // File Path:E:\Android\data\com.syedabdullah.syed.quran_memorization_application
>             //                          \files\Quran Memorization Application\Quran_Pictures
>             //So first create a root folder Quran Memorization Application then inside that
>             //folder we create another folder named Quran Pictures.
>
>        /*     File rootFolder = new File(getExternalFilesDir("Quran Memorization Application"),
>                     "Quran_Pages"); */
>
>             //Here we insert inside the Quran_Pictures folder the quran_pages.
>             //String myFileName = "quran_01.jpg";
>             Bundle y = new Bundle();
>             int retrievePos = y.getInt("i");
>             String quranFilePageName = "_" + retrievePos + ".jpg";
>           //  String fileName = "justwork.jpg";
>             File sup = new File(getExternalFilesDir("Quran Memorization Application"), "Quran_Pages");
>             File myFile = new File(sup, quranFilePageName);
>             myFile.createNewFile();
>
>             //downlaod the file.
>             input = connection.getInputStream();
>             output = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
>
>             byte data[] = new byte[4096];
>             long total = 0;
>             int count;
>             while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
>                 //allow cancel with back button.
>                 if (isCancelled()) {
>                     input.close();
>                     return null;
>                 }
>                 total += count;
>                 //publish the progress.
>                 if (fileLength > 0) {
>                     publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
>                 }
>                 output.write(data, 0, count);
>             }
>             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
>             intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(myFile));
>             QuranActivity.this.sendBroadcast(intent);
>         } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         } catch (IOException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         } finally {
>             try {
>                 if (output != null) {
>                     output.close();
>                 }
>                 if (input != null) {
>                     input.close();
>                 }
>
>             } catch (IOException e) {
>                 e.printStackTrace();
>             }
>             if (connection != null) {
>                 connection.disconnect();
>             }
>         }
>         return null;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onPreExecute() {
>         super.onPreExecute();
>         //Take CPU lock to prevent CPU from going off if the user presses the power button.
>         //during download.
>         PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
>         myWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, getClass().getName());
>         myWakeLock.acquire();
>         myProgressDialog.show();
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
>         super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
>         //If we get here length is known, so setIndertimante to false.
>         myProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
>         myProgressDialog.setMax(100);
>         myProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
>         myWakeLock.release();
>         myProgressDialog.dismiss();
>         if (result != null) {
>             Toast.makeText(context, "Download error: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>         } else {
>             Toast.makeText(context, "Download Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>         }
>
>     }
> } }
> ```

I was hoping to have a for loop that would create hundreds of downloadTasks and download all the images I need, and then I would call the get method. However in order for that to work, I first need too know why when I try for 2 images only the first one gets downloaded and why no progressbar shows up. Also if possible if I could get a hint as to how I can make my progressBar update for all the images and not be designed for just 1. Thanks in advance. (Note all URLs are currect.)

Comment: `and then I would call the get method`. No. Never use the get method. It undoes asynchronity. Just use a for loop in the doInBackground of one AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much! figured out that my loops were suppose to go inside doInBackground. Also to anyone else having a similar issue. To download multiple files and display a decent progressBar, here is a very great tutorial: http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/dialog/android-download-multiple-files-showing-progress-bar/

Comment: Sorry I can't accept my answer so will come back and mark as solved (since I recently found answer to another question).